# Why is my value saved to SharedPreferences in onPause() not restored in onResume()?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-preferences

I have the following code:

```
    SharedPreferences KITPrefs;
    EditText passPhraseExample;

...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        passPhraseExample = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassPhraseExample);
        KITPrefs = getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        passPhraseExample.setText(KITPrefs.getString("passPhraseExample", ""));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = KITPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("passPhraseExample", passPhraseExample.getText()
                .toString());
    }
```

..yet when I enter a value in "passPhraseExample," move to the next Activity, and then go back (in the Emulator), the passPhraseExample EditText is empty. Shouldn't it have the value I entered into it, saved, and then "restored"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't commit your changes.
Call `editor.commit()` after writing the string in `onPause()`. Otherwise your changes are not saved.